# How to protect access to multiple docker hosts with the same TLS certificates

Tags: docker, ssl

I'm following the [instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/protect-access/#use-tls-https-to-protect-the-docker-daemon-socket) about protecting Docker Daemon sockets for remote access using TLS certificate. The approach works fine for me when I have say 2 VMs, host1 and host2, with docker hosts installed on them each having individual self signed CAs with CommonNames equal to these hosts. In results, I have 2 sets of client certificates, and 2 sets of server certificates to generate, secure and distribute.

Now I'm looking for a way to share singe pair of client + server certificates, that will allow clients to connect to any of host1 or host2 or hostN. Is it possible?

Looks like Docker the certificates against the actual host or IP it connects to:

> $ docker ps -a
> error during connect: Get "https://100.120.41.6:2376/v1.24/containers/json?all=1": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate is valid for 100.120.41.10, not 100.120.41.6

Is there a way to generate some generic certificate for such case?

Comment: If you use *hostnames* instead of *ip addresses* you can create a [wildcard certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate) that can be used to verify all hosts in a single domain (e.g., if you create a certificate for `*.my.testing.domain`, then it would be valid for `vm1.my.testing.domain` and `vm2.my.testing.domain`).